# ActiveX component can't create object: 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0'

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm getting an error:

> ActiveX component can't create object: 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0'

With this line of code:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

I'm very naive when it comes to IIS. Is this an IIS configuration issue or something up with the code?

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Server.CreateObject instead of CreateObject

CreateObject (without the Server. bit) is for client side vbscript

Comment: I'll give you the win. I got there with Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Comment: Microsoft.XMLHTTP is an older version of Microsoft's xml processor, but it should do the job just as well